# Zero, the Additive Identity, as the Multiplicative Annihilator

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

In the structures I have encountered so far, I have always seen a zero, which is usually defined as the additive identity. For example:

> $\exists 0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}, a + 0 = 0+a = a$

It just so happens to be that whenever the need arose, $0$ also served as the multiplicative annihilator, i.e. where $X$ is some commutative ring: $\forall a \in X, a \cdot 0 = 0$, as proven below:

> $0=0$, so $0+0 = 0$, so $a\cdot(0+0) = a \cdot 0$, so $a\cdot 0 + a \cdot 0 = a \cdot 0$, so $0 = a \cdot 0$.

My question is whether the zero **always** serves as the multiplicative annihilator as well, whether this is actually part of its definition (or an always-implicit corollary), or if it is possible to have a zero that does not serve as a multiplicative annihilator.

Comment: The answers so far have referred to rings, for which the multiplicative-annihilative property of zero follows almost directly from the axioms. What if we consider structures that are not rings (but in which multiplication and addition are still somehow connected)? (Do such structures even exist?)

Comment: well, structures can always be made to *exist*; rings are useful as such since so many things *are* rings.  But there have got to be other two-operation algebraic structures with other rules which tie the operations together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is clear from the OP's argument:

$0a = (0 + 0)a = 0a + 0a \Rightarrow 0a = 0 \tag{1}$

that $0$ being a multiplicative annihilator depends on two things:  i.)  the fact that zero is the identity element for the "$+$" operation; and (ii.)  the fact that multiplication distributes over addition in the sense that $a(b + c) = a(b + c)$.  So, if you want the zero element to *not* be a multiplicative annihilator, you'll have to bust one of these postulates.  Well, busting the additive identity won't work and leave us with an Abelian group under "$+$"; thus we'd have to let go of distributivity, the axiom which ties addition and multiplication together.  If *that* postulate is eliminated or severely altered, all I can say is:

***We'll be left with something VERY un-ring like!***

So, as long as we want rings to be ***rings***, as it were, we have to accept $0$ as multiplicative annihilator that it is.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: That's actually quite helpful! It's beneficial to think of this in terms of having to 'bust the postulates'. Cheers!

Comment: @Newb:  Well, that's logic for ya'!  And thanks for the kind words.  Best, RKL

Comment: It's really an argument by contraposition, like *reducto ad absurdum* (sort of).

Answer (score 3):

It is a theorem on rings (all rings) that $x0=0$ for all $x$. This is not part of the definition, it follows from simpler axioms.

$$
\begin{align}
x0&=x0+0=x(0+0)=x0+x0\\
x0&=x0+x0\\
x0&=0
\end{align}
$$

The proof for $0x=0$ is similar.